# Python - сортировка обьектов с помощью __gt__ operator

Tags: python, классы, сортировка

Для чего служит функция _gt__(self, other) ?
Ведь сравнивать атрибуты классов можно с помощью atrgetter, хочу понять для чего она нужна и чем удобно, а также можно ли ее использовать если есть массив с обьектами и их нужно отсортировать по атрибутам. Ниже пример - хочу отсортировать обьекты по атрибуту side

```
class Shape:

    array = list()


    def __init__(self, side):
        self.side = side
        self.add_to_array(self)

    def __gt_(self, other):
        return self.side > other.side

    @classmethod
    def add_to_array(cls, object):
        cls.array.append(object)

class Square(Shape):

    def __init__(self, side):
        super().__init__(side)





square = Square(5)
new_shape = Shape(4)

for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] > array[i+1]
       ? Вернет True?
```

Answer (score 1):

`object.__gt__(self, other)` позволяет реализовать проверку на «больше чем» для экземпляров пользовательских типов, где:

- self : Ссылка на экземпляр
- other : Объект с которым следует произвести сравнение (справа от
  оператора сравнения)

Метод может возбудить исключение `NotImplemented`, если сравнение для указанной пары аргументов не реализовано.

В соответствии с договорённостью в случае успешного сравнения возвращает `True`, либо `False`. Однако, может возвращать и любое другое значение, таким образом, если результат сравнения будет использован в контексте Булева типа (например в условии `if`), Python произведёт вызов `bool()` для интерпретации данного значения.

Начиная с ***Python 3.4***:

> Если операнды имеют различные типы и тип правого операнда является
>   прямым или косвенным наследником типа левого операнда то
>   метод-отражение правого операнда имеет приоритет, в иных случаях
>   приоритет остаётся у метода левого операнда. При этом виртуальное
>   наследование не учитывается.

**Выводы:** таким образом `object.__gt__(self, other)` используется в сравнении вида `object1 > object2` и только в этом случае. Его можно использовать при сравнении атрибутов, в случае реализации по одному атрибуту(как в вашем примере), объекты будут сравниваться имеено по нему. Но основное его предназначение - это "глубокое" сравнение объектов в целом между собой, а то - по одному или нескольким атрибутам будет происходить сравнение - решать уже непосредственно Вам.

## UPD#1

В дополнение к ответу, вы также можете реализовать специальный метод `object.__lt__(self, other)` («меньше чем») в классе. Метод `sort()` (и функция `sorted()`) сможет сравнить объекты и тем самым отсортировать их. Тем не менее, это лучше всего работает, когда вы будете сортировать их только по этому атрибуту. Оба этих метода будут сортировать элементы используя сравнение «меньше чем» (то есть в порядке возрастания).

Вообще говоря, методы `object.__gt__(self, other)` и `object.__lt__(self, other)` считаются зеркальными. Если левый класс не переопределяет соответствующий метод, или соответствующий метод возвращает NotImplemented, то во время выполнения Python будет заменять аргументы и вызывать метод отражения, определенный в классе, стоящем справа.

## UPD#2

Как правило для гибкой сортировки экземпляров классов(с помощью встроенных функций)  используют следующие варианты:

- operator.itemgetter(item), operator.itemgetter(*items)
- operator.attrgetter(attr), operator.attrgetter(*attrs)
- lambda - работает медленнее, чем первые два варианта